# How to migrate from certificate-based Kubernetes integration to the Gitlab agent for Kubernetes

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have some integration tubes for more than a year working without any problem. And I realize that until this month February 2023 support for the integration of certified-based Kubernetes ends. So I have to migrate to using something called Gitlab agent. Which apparently exists a few days ago and I had not noticed. I have created the agent without problems in my Kubernetes cluster following the gitlab documentation, but I have a small problem.

How can I tell my CI/CD workflow to stop using my old certificate-based integration and now start using my new Gitlab agent to authenticate/authorize/integrate with my kubernetes cluster.

I have followed these instructions https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/clusters/migrate_to_gitlab_agent.html
But the part I'm not quite clear on is what additional instructions I should add to my .gitlab-ci.yml file to tell it to use the gitlab agent.

I already created gitlab agent, created config.yaml, also gitlab says that they are connected with my GKE.

Try adding a tag in my config.yaml like this.

```
ci_access:
   projects:
     -id: path/to/project
```

In the same way, the integration pipeline worked without problems, but I am sure that it is working because it is connected in the other way. Any way to ensure that it is working with the gitlab agent?